# I run a timer for each http request I get, I'd want to add a loadbalancer but the second request may/will not be sent to the right backend server

Tags: node.js, webserver, load-balancing, digital-ocean

I run a timer per user API request (over HTTP).

I want to grow horizontally (adding servers) but if I had some servers behind a loadbalancer the user may not be sent to the same backend server for the second request and my timing function wouldn't work.

If I could use cookies it would be easy with sticky sessions.

I can recognize the user using a parameter in the URL but I would prefer not to have to create my own loadbalancing scheme using Nginx or similar solutions.

If that helps:
- App is in nodejs
- Hosted at DigitalOcean.

Anyone struck by a great idea?